# ¿Como Actualizar datagrid?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen día, quiero que mi datagrid se actualiza de forma automatica, he intentado con esta linea de codigo;

> this.almacenTableAdapter.Fill(this.almacenDataSet.almacen);

pero no he podido hacerlo, las pestañas sin windows forms, las hago asi con el tab control y un pequeño codigo para que se visualizen en el tab control.

el que dice form 4, es el formulario principal, desde ahi hago las llamadas para que se muestren otros formularios, como el form3.

[image: Cada numero indica un formulario diferente]

Comment: Podes hacer un método que se active al guardar el dato exitosamente y que este haga la consulta a la BD inmediatamente y que refresque el gridview.

Comment: Pero los datos que muestro en el datagrid es un origen de datos, no estoy haciendo ninguna consulta

Comment: A qué te referís con un origen de datos?

Comment: cuando el datagrid lo enlazas a la base de datos desde el diseñador

Comment: Por desgracia nunca he trabajado de esa manera por lo que no puedo ayudarte. Te recomiendo que en lugar de hacer un bind de esa manera, guardes los datos en un objeto, como ser una lista o una binding list, de esta manera tendrás mayor flexibilidad a la hora de hacer uso de esa información. Seguramente alguien con mayor conocimiento al respecto te ayudará! Saludos.

Comment: @Macx, la actulizacion de un DataGridView, se la realiza atravez de un `BindingSource` y de un `DataSet`, al conectar a la base de datos se crean ambos, el `DataSet` es el modelo o tabla de tu base de datos, y el el `BidingSource` debe ser una funcion que retorne un `DataTable` con los datos-columnas de tu `DataSet`(modelo o tabla). No puedo ayudarte mas porque no se las variables que utilizas para producir este, pero si encuentras estos no te sera dificil "actualizar tu datagrid".

Comment: Ya me quedo, muchas gracias por sus comentarios